# Getting weird 404 error in my online portfolio. Firefox only issue

Tags: firefox, http-status-code-404

When I click on one of the icons for my online art portfolio, it is supposed to make the picture pop up on the same page. However for Firefox, when I click on an icon, it goes to a 404 page. If I go back, that picture will pop up. I have been told that on the newest version of Firefox, or version 28 I think, has no issues. I have 27.something.

This does not happen on any other browser.

Also I made the animation of the picture popping up with Adobe Edge, the CC version.

Here is my site- http://spencerheisedesign.com/gallery.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried viewing the page in a private window? Maybe it's a caching issue.